# How do I detect a string in multi-line output and set a variable based on substring in one line in bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

My scripting knowledge in bash is very basic and I've cobbled together stuff in the past to accomplish some automation I need over the years.

The latest project is about some video processing, and based on a format of the file, I want to do some post-processing.

ffprobe will output meta-data about a video file, with the following excerpt:

```
ISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=eng
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=dts
codec_long_name=DCA (DTS Coherent Acoustics)
profile=DTS
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
```

In particular, i want to detect whether or not the string `codec_name=dts` is present, then get the index value represented in the line prior.  In the above case, it does contain `codec_name=dts`, and I want to be able to use the value `1` later in the script because of the line `index=1` right before it.

In my script, I'm using this logic to do the first string detection using grep:

```
if (/usr/sbin/ffprobe -show_streams -i "$source"  | grep -q "codec_name=dts"); then
    <do some work here>
fi
```

What's the best way to do what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
| awk -F "=" '$1=="index"{i=$2}; /codec_name=dts/{print i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` you can check whether `index=?` is followed by `code_name=dts` in the output. Something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/sbin/ffprobe -show_streams -i "$source" > metadatafile.txt
val=$(grep -B1 'codec_name=dts' metadatafile.txt  | grep -o -P '(?<=index=)[0-9]+$') 

# Make sure $val is a number, kinda redundant because above `grep` takes care of that.
if [[ $val =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "Doing some work here with $val"
fi
```